# Logitech K760 Pair with one logitech usb dongle

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

My Operating System is is Ubuntu 18.04 and my machine does not have a built in Bluetooth device. I have a Logitech mouse and its usb-dongle, both work fine.

I can see the mouse as a paired device at Solaar application and it says "Up to 6 devices can be paired to this receiver".

My problem is that I can not pair my Logitech Keyboard K730.
I have the following information from my machine

```
hciconfig scan
Can't get device info: No such device

hcitool dev
Devices:
```

So, the Logitech dongle is not recognized as a device. My main question is if I can pair Logitech K760 to logitech unifying receiver as second device or not?

Comment: Pair it in Windows, reboot to Ubuntu, and you should be fine.

Comment: I already paired it in windows. I have two machines one is windows and the other one is ubuntu. I am fine with windows as first device but I would like to use the same keyboard in ubuntu as a second device, then switching back and forth between windows and ubuntu will be easy for me. What do you really mean by reboot to ubuntu? @heynnema

Comment: It's unclear now what you're doing. You have TWO different computers, and ONE Logitech unifying USB dongle? If that's the case, you'll need to pair your mouse and keyboard using Windows, then unplug the dongle and plug it into your Ubuntu computer. Reboot means to startup Ubuntu by selecting it in the GRUB menu.

Comment: I did what you told me but this keyboard is not really compatible with Windows because unifying software can not even pair my keyboard. But it is fine on Windows machines with built-in Bluetooth device.

Comment: If the K730/K760 is a bluetooth (only) device, then you won't be able to pair it using the Logitech Unifying software in Windows, or Solaar in Ubuntu. You'll need to pair it using bluetooth.